# Way around battery controller limiting maximum charge of new cells

Tags: batteries, eeprom, controller

I rebuilt a camera battery (NP-F550) and need clarification as to what is going wrong.
The battery charges and powers the camera without issue, but will only charge for ~5 minutes before charging stops. The camera runs for ~7 minutes on that charge. The cells are brand new, rated at 1800mAh, and are genuine. I was expecting them to take more than 5 minutes to reach their full capacity, so I'm assuming that the battery controller is cutting them off long before that happens. I did try charging for a couple hours, which produced the same result.

The cells that are being replaced are only rated at 1250mAh. I expected the new cells would only charge up to the old ceiling, but clearly it's capped much lower. Is it possible that there is some EEPROM on this controller that adjusted the charge ceiling while the old cells degraded? If that's the case, is there any way around that?

I gave my best shot at trying to identify the parts on the controller and only came up with a link for the IC labeled AV4X S8232B [(EDIT: Link provided by user253751)](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/360/S8232_E-18368.pdf). I have no clue where to look past searching the labels, if that can even help. The controller is labeled ZN-L04A V200 on its back.
[image: ZN-L04A V200 controller]

So what can be done to charge the cells more? What am I overlooking? I am most definitely not an electrical engineer, so apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: What voltage do the cells reach after charging stops?

Comment: I know that some chips will try to count the total coulombs going into and out of the battery. I don't know if that's what's happening here. Yes, it could also adjust the charge level depending on battery degradation if it is quite highly advanced. There are a lot more components on this circuit board than I'd expect on a simple, generic battery protection circuit.

Comment: [Here is the datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/360/S8232_E-18368.pdf) for the S2832 protection chip I can read the label of. It does not feature any kind of memory.

Comment: @Polynomial This might be the root of the problem! The voltage on the first cell is just over 4V, where the second is at 3.5V. The joint connecting the battery tabs is actually quite big, and should be redone. I can only imagine that big joints can cause a wide range of different issues, especially if the joint connects the 2 batteries.

Comment: @user253751 thank you for the link, I've added it to the post now, I really should have provided it in the first place. Also good to know there's no memory, it's looking like the issue is me rather than the hardware.

And thank you both for the swift replies. I'll try and redo the solder job tomorrow and post my results.

Comment: @zuzomuzabi I don't see how a  mechanical joint would cause any electrical problem. Bad joints can exhibit high resistance and get hot; they can also get loose and break the connection; but they can't really cause the cells to become unbalanced.

Comment: The circuit board might have circuitry to balance the cells (that would explain why it's got more than a few parts on it). The middle joint should connect to somewhere on the circuit board; did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the cells got unbalanced before I soldered them in.

All I needed to do was drain the first cell (done by attaching alligator clips to a device that required 4v), and then put the pack back into the charger. Has worked since.